# WP-rest API response too big

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

When I call a wp rest API the response is too big around 1.5 mb which makes my mobile app very slow. How can I determine what fields the wp-rest API should return?

example:
instead of getting

```
"tags": [],
    "better_featured_image": {
      "id": 13668,
      "alt_text": "",
      "caption": "Solicitud real ante la dificil situacion de los refugiados sirios bloqueados entre Argelia y Marruecos",
      "description": "",
      "media_type": "image",
      "media_details": {
        "width": 675,
        "height": 402,
        "file": "2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5.jpg",
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "file": "sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-150x89.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 89,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://infomarruecos.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-150x89.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "file": "sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-300x179.jpg",
            "width": 300,
            "height": 179,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://infomarruecos.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-300x179.jpg"
          },
          "slgf_12_thumb": {
            "file": "sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-500x402.jpg",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 402,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://infomarruecos.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-500x402.jpg"
          },
```

get only the medium size

```
"better_featured_image": {
      "id": 13668,
      "alt_text": "",
      "caption": "Solicitud real ante la dificil situacion de los refugiados sirios bloqueados entre Argelia y Marruecos",
      "description": "",
      "media_type": "image",
      "media_details": {
        "width": 675,
        "height": 402,
        "file": "2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5.jpg",
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "file": "sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-150x89.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 89,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://infomarruecos.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-150x89.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "file": "sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-300x179.jpg",
            "width": 300,
            "height": 179,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://infomarruecos.ma/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/sm-le-roi-ceremonie-mawlid-nabawi-g1-504x300_5-300x179.jpg"
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

my theme was generating to much image for responsivity so the rest api ketp sending back all available images . i will try to add custom endpoint